# I want to create a similar structure as in the image

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ca6R8.png)

I want to create a similar structure as in the image. odd div should have a specific common position and even to have the same but different position.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Use grid to achieve the basic structure.
2. Add `margin-top` value to every 2nd child.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6,1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.item {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px dashed red;
}

.item:nth-child(2n) {
  background: red;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```